# How to generate arff file from ACE

Tags: prolog, weka, inductive-logic-programming

I am using the ACE data mining package https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/ACE/doc/ACEuser-1.2.16.pdf which uses inductive logic programming.

I am using WARMR to find frequent queries.

In the manual it has a command 'generate_arff' but this command does not seem to be in my version.(Windows). By typing help into ACE it lists the command 'generate_arff/2' but the help does not give any indication what the arguments should be (Presumably an input file and an output file) I have not been able to guess how this works. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Ps I would like to tag this as ILP and Warmr but I do not have the ability. Also I don't think the ACE tag matchs my use.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that you'll find here much help. ACE download is restricted, maybe you should post your question to the developers group.

Comment: I have emailed the professor in charge.. just thought it might be worth asking here, but not sure how many people using ACE will see the question..

Comment: `generate_arff('warmr3/my_example.freq_queries.out','warmr3/my_example.txt').` worked for me on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate_arff('my_program.freq_queries.out','my_program.arff').

This does not work in windows for some reason, but works in Linux